# Reproduzindo audio/streaming ionic 3

Tags: javascript, ionic, apache-cordova, ionic3, cordova-plugin

Plugin usado na resolução: 
https://github.com/amitkhare/cordova-music-controls-plugin

como adicionar essa função da imagem de pausar a musica/audio/streaming que esta tocando no ionic?
Eu estou reproduzindo uma webradio, quando estou visualizando o app no navegador, se eu minimizar a tela ele aparece essa função para pausar o audio, mas quando eu realizo o build do aplicativo ele não mostra essa tela quando minimiza o aplicativo.

Eu já tentei reproduzir de varias maneiras: 
Usando a tag audio direto no html:
`<audio controls src="LINK_STREAMING" autoplay></audio>`
Usando o plugin NativeAudio: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/native-audio/ 
Usando o plugin Media: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/media/

Mas nenhuma das opções coloca a opção para o usuario pausar o audio com a tela do celular bloqueada.

Já tentei usar o plugin: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/music-controls/ mas após instalar usando a documentação ele não build o app, fica dando erro por esta depreciado, mensagem de erro: https://pastebin.com/dGKKnsbZ?

Imagem de como eu gostaria de deixar:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Tem que usar o plugin Background mode , se não toda vez que o celular for desligado depois de um tempo vai parar o áudio.

Ele é bem fácil de usar

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode#usage